# Nginx file upload does not work

Tags: nginx, upload, cloudflare

I have a server running nginx and php-fpm and I am having issues with uploading files bigger than a few hundred kbytes. Small files are just fine, but anything above 2-300 kbytes start to upload, then it never actually finishes, nginx does not even send any reply (eventually, the server drops the connection according to netstat, Chrome displays an EMPTY_RESPONSE error page after a while).

Nor nginx, neither php-fpm error logs contain any relevant entries.

The strange thing is, I used to have CloudFlare enabled. The problem started to appear when I disabled it. When I enable it again, the problem disappears and I can upload files without any issues. Could you please help me with identifying the issue?

Here's my`nginx.conf` file:

```
user <myuser>;
worker_processes auto;
pid /run/nginx.pid;

events {
        worker_connections 512;
        multi_accept on;
}

http {

        ##
        # Basic Settings
        ##

        sendfile on;
        tcp_nopush on;
        tcp_nodelay on;
        keepalive_timeout 65;
        types_hash_max_size 2048;
        # server_tokens off;

        # server_names_hash_bucket_size 64;
        # server_name_in_redirect off;

        include /etc/nginx/mime.types;
        default_type application/octet-stream;


        client_max_body_size 100M;

        ##
        # SSL Settings
        ##

        ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2; # Dropping SSLv3, ref: POODLE
        ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;

        ##
        # Logging Settings
        ##

        access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
        error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;

        ##
        # Gzip Settings
        ##

        gzip on;
        gzip_disable "msie6";

        # gzip_vary on;
        # gzip_proxied any;
        # gzip_comp_level 6;
        # gzip_buffers 16 8k;
        # gzip_http_version 1.1;
        gzip_types text/plain text/css application/json application/javascript text/xml application/xml application/xml+rss text/javascript;

        ##
        # Virtual Host Configs
        ##

        include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
        include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*;
}
```

Comment: Are you sure you're not enabling cloudflare and not disabling it? Also, do you have anything sat infront of this? eg varnish / ssltermination ?

Comment: Yes, Cloudflare is paused. No, it is directly nginx. Also, the strangest part I just discovered today: it only fails on Windows. Mobile devices / Macs work just fine. But all major browsers on Windows fail to upload anything larger than a few kbytes (tested on many different machines).

Comment: Also, I checked out the upload process with tcpdump, the beginning of the data arrives just fine, then the rest comes in parts with a few second pause between them, and it eventually just times out.